# PHP OOP: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I have a real hard time understanding why the below code doesn't work as intended. I've usually use the [bucket](https://github.com/troelskn/bucket) dependency injector, but to simplify, I've used [twittee](https://github.com/fabpot/twittee) below, with the very same result.

So why aren't my modified `Config`-object (and the created setting-element) available to the `MockObject`-class? From what I can tell, it's being passed correctly.

Code:

```
$c = new Container();
$c->config = function ($c) { return new Config(); };
$config = $c->config;
$config->setting = 'a value';
$c->MockObject = function ($c) { return new MockObject($c->config); };
$c->MockObject; // Error thrown: `Notice: Undefined index: setting`
```

Classes:

```
class Container {
    protected $s=array();
    function __set($k, $c) { $this->s[$k]=$c; }
    function __get($k) { return $this->s[$k]($this); }
}

class Config {
    public $values = array();
    function __set($key, $value){ $this->values[$key] = $value; }
    function __get($key) { return $this->values[$key]; }    
}

class MockObject {
    function __construct(Config $config) { echo $config->setting; }
}
```

Dependency injection container courtesy of Fabien Potencier; https://github.com/fabpot/twittee

Comment: "I've used twittee below, with the very same result." What result are you getting?

Comment: Note: A more robust version of twitee is Pimple: http://pimple-project.org Also by Fabien Potencier.

Comment: Yep - know that. Just using twitee to show what I am doing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not extremely familiar with DI on PHP, but I think your problem is in this line:

```
$c->config = function ($c) { return new Config(); };
```

Your original code was

```
$config = $c->config = function ($c) { return new Config(); };
```

I'm guessing this threw an exception on `$config->setting = 'a value'`.  `$config` and `$c->config` were both defined as a Closure that would return a new `Config` object.  Since `$config` was a Closure, it would never have a `setting` property.

Your updated code is

```
$c->config = function ($c) { return new Config(); };  // $c->config is a closure as described
$config = $c->config;  // $config is a new Config object
```

Now `$config` is being defined as a `Config` class, not a Closure, so `$configure->setting` is valid.
However, `$c->config` still refers to a Closure returning a new `Config` object.  Since this new `Config` object doesn't have a property named "Setting" it's throwing an error when you try to retrieve it.

I'm not sure how it fits with the rest of your design, but the following should work as expected:

```
$c->MockObject = function ($c) { return new MockObject($config); };
```